# How to check if an occurrence of a string is visible on a page using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, visibility

There are several questions out there that resemble this one.  But I did not found this exact question on SO. (nor the answer elsewhere).

I just need to know if a string is showing *AT LEAST ONCE*. It might be possible that the string occurs more than once in the HTML, that it is hidden one time and showing another time.

It's about **visibility** in the page, not necessarily in the viewport. Thus if you have to scroll to view it, that is OK too.

UPDATE: I know of `:contains` and `is(":visible")` that's not the problem. Elements can be nested deep of course, and it has to work in all circumstances.

Comment: If the string has such a specific meaning would it not be wrapped inside a `span` or similar for example which you have decorated with a data attribute or class that should make this easier?

Comment: I'm looking for a generic solution, I don't know beforehand where it can be wrapped in

Comment: Hmm... I think that you would have to work backwards from the element containing the text, and check each parent for visibility until you get to the body element.

Comment: How is it going to be "hidden"? With any css property?

Comment: with any css property or javascript

Comment: Is it wrapped in anything in all circunstances?

Comment: @Peter: I know this doesn't help you :( - This seems all very brittle/hacky. If you have an important string on your page but it is not important enough to wrap it in a specific element or class but important enough to want to base functionality on it's occurrence then the implementation looks very strange/flaky. If the text is hidden using CSS then use the selectors from the different CSS styles to determine the occurrence. If you have script randomly hide text without using classes or attributes then that implementation of that script also is flaky.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl like i said : i'm looking for sth. generic.  I'm finetuning a test-application. I want endusers to be able to say :"this text has to be visible, but not visible anymore when I click this button" stuff like that. I am aware of plenty of frameworks for similar usecases, but that's another discussion.

Comment: Say you're looking for "aaa", do you want "<span>a</span>aa" to match? The user will see "aaa" but it's quite complex to take such cases into account (you might need an entire HTML parser).

Comment: @Japer : good point.  In that case I would want it to match.  But all that is not such a problem in real life for me. The accepted answer was enough to solve my problems.

Comment: minus voter, please explain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work, but it is not the most efficient solution though:

```
$("body, body *").contents().filter(function () {
    return this.nodeType === 3 && this.nodeValue.indexOf("Foo & Bar") >= 0;
}).parent(":visible");
```

This code:

- Locates all *text* nodes in the document that contain the specified string <sup>1</sup>
- And checks if their parent is visible <sup>2</sup>

<sup>1</sup> This means the deepest node that contains the string. The `:contains` selector would be useless because it could return a visible element (in fact a branch of elements) that contains an invisible child that contains the specified string.

<sup>2</sup> An element is visible if its parents are visible as well

Comment: Salman, great work!  I'll have to do some more tests and accept it later,but tx in each case!

Comment: I won't have time now to test thoroughly , I accepted for now so I cannot forget.   A very simple test can be found here : http://jsfiddle.net/7caG5/1/

Comment: I just checked it against a website that uses popup menus. When searching for text that is inside popup menu, it returns zero nodes when popup is hidden and one node when menu is visible. So I am positive it should work.

Comment: ok, tx again, about your title-edit : i know jquery is a js framework, but I wanted an answer either in jquery or plain js.  Not in any other js framework. Never mind though, I have my answer already

Answer (score 0):

You can use [:contains](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) over your body element together with `length`, which count the number of matches.

```
if($('body:contains("demo")').length){
    alert("The world exists");
}else{
    alert("The world doesn't exist");   
};
```

Comment: That is also taking in account invisible text